# Setting Rails/Rack Environment When Using Docker Compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I have a docker-compose environment as follows:

```
web:
build: .
environment:
  - RAILS_ENV=development
  - RACK_ENV=development
  - DOCKERIZED=true
env_file: 
  - .env
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
volumes:
  - .:/usr/app    
links:
  - redis
  - db
  - search
  - memcache
networks:
  - front-tier
  - back-tier
command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```

In my .env file I have the following:

```
RAILS_ENV=development
RACK_ENV=development
```

The problem is that when I try to seed the database using

```
docker-compose run web bundle exec rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=development
```

When seeding the database, **the output of 'Rails.env' in the log is 'production'**. When I run

```
docker-compose run web env
```

It get the following environment variables:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=b6fcc864cf45
TERM=xterm
DOCKERIZED=true
RACK_ENV=development
RAILS_ENV=development
```

However, when I run the following command:

```
docker-compose run web rails r "print Rails.env"
```

I get:

```
> production
```

So something is causing my web container to think it is in a production environment. I have set RAILS_ENV as an environment variable in the Dockerfile for the web container, and also launch the server with:

```
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-e", "development"]
```

This is also causing problems because I can't connect to my redis instance which is in a separate container because Rails is picking up the production settings and mapping to 'localhost' instead of the 'redis' container.

We're using Ruby 2.3.1 (under RVM) and Rails 4.2.6. We're using Docker Compose 1.8.0.

This setup worked perfectly about a month ago so we suspect that somewhere along the line a small change crept into the stack with the purpose of making my life miserable.

To summarize my question: where is Rails picking up the incorrect environment? I've checked all the known places.

Comment: are you using a gem that loads `.env` files for variables like dotenv-rails? Is `RAILS_ENV` in the .env file at all?

Comment: That's super weird. 1. Do you have anything else which could affect env? Like `dotenv-rails` + `.env.local` file. Cuz `env` shell command shows correct values. There should be smth either in gems, or in codebase (like `ENV['RAILS_ENV']= = 'production'`). 2. Btw check the value of `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` to know if it's updated. 3. Search codebase for `production` mentions

Answer (score -1):

To complete @faron's answer :

Theres is couple misstakes in your docker-compose configuration :

1. `web` section indentation (the whole sub-block should be indented to the right)
2. `environment` section is not an array, but key-value pairs
3. `env_file` section is useless, all variables defined in `.env` are overwritten by `environment` section.
4. both `environment` and `env_file` sections are loaded at runtime, but most of the time, `RAILS_ENV` is also required for container build phase.

Here is usually what I do for my rails containers (takes advantage of DOCKER_BUILDKIT, which is now used by default in docker-compose I think) :

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:3.1.0 AS development
WORKDIR /app
ENV RAILS_ENV=development
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install --quiet
COPY . .
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "--environment=development"]

FROM ruby:3.1.0 AS production
WORKDIR /app
ENV RAILS_ENV=production
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install --quiet --jobs 20 --retry 5 --without development test
COPY . .
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "--environment=production"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - my_network
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker compose up
```